# Why doesn't Element.attrib include namespace definitions?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml-namespaces

I'd like to create a XML namespace mapping (e.g., to use in `findall` calls as in [the Python documentation of ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces)). Given the definitions seem to exist as attributes of the `xbrl` root element, I'd have thought I could just examine the `attrib` attribute of the `root` element within my `ElementTree`. However, the following code

```
from io import StringIO
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


TEST = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xbrl
  xml:lang="en-US"
  xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"
  xmlns:country="http://xbrl.sec.gov/country/2021"
  xmlns:dei="http://xbrl.sec.gov/dei/2021q4"
  xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217"
  xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"
  xmlns:nvda="http://www.nvidia.com/20220130"
  xmlns:srt="http://fasb.org/srt/2021-01-31"
  xmlns:stpr="http://xbrl.sec.gov/stpr/2021"
  xmlns:us-gaap="http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2021-01-31"
  xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  </xbrl>'''


xbrl = ET.parse(StringIO(TEST))
print(xbrl.getroot().attrib)
```

produces the following output:

```
{'{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang': 'en-US'}
```

Why aren't any of the namespace attributes showing up in `root.attrib`? I'd at least expect `xlmns` to be in the dictionary given it has no prefix.

**What have I tried?**

The following code seems to work to generate the namespace mapping:

```
print({prefix: uri for key, (prefix, uri) in ET.iterparse(StringIO(TEST), events=['start-ns'])})
```

output:

```
{'': 'http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance',
'country': 'http://xbrl.sec.gov/country/2021',
'dei': 'http://xbrl.sec.gov/dei/2021q4',
'iso4217': 'http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217',
'link': 'http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase',
'nvda': 'http://www.nvidia.com/20220130',
'srt': 'http://fasb.org/srt/2021-01-31',
'stpr': 'http://xbrl.sec.gov/stpr/2021',
'us-gaap': 'http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2021-01-31',
'xbrldi': 'http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi',
'xlink': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink',
'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'}
```

But yikes is it gross to have to parse the file twice.

Comment: A namespace declaration such as `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` is syntactically an attribute. But as you noticed, it is not an attribute in the data structure created when parsing the XML document. The XML Information Set specification defines attributes and namespaces as separate "information items": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Information_Set. See also http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/NamespacesFAQ.htm#decl.

Comment: But don't you only need to extract namespaces once? Why bother to add, say, `xmlns:nvda="http://www.nvidia.com/20220130"` to a namespace map if you didn't already know apriori that you were going to use "nvda:whatever" in an xpath later? You can do the iterparse thing once as an easy way to get a namespace dict for this type of document and then copy that into your scripts as needed. More generally, namespaces usually imply schema that you have to know about to know which type of thing to search for. The namespace dict just seems like a small part of it.

Comment: `lxml` will include an `nsmap` on elements so you could change to using a different toolset. Namespaces can be declared on any element, so you'd still have to scan.

Comment: @tdelaney I know I'm searching for `nvda:whatever`, but the uris change at varying frequencies (for `nvda`, roughly quarterly). For example, in the following quarter's financial results, `xmlns:nvda="http://www.nvidia.com/20220430"`. It feels like I'd have to change the hard-coded namespace mapping every financial report, even if I knew I was always looking for `nvda:units`.

Comment: Namespaces should only change infrequently... only when the schema for that namespace changes. Maybe fields are added or deleted. I was a bit surprised that these seem relatively new. I've been out of the XML business for some time, but for the stuff I was working on, a schema URI change was a notable event. I'd be tempted to track current schema and if the script fails to scan the xml properly, then look for changes. Maybe not a satisfying solution in all cases, though.

Comment: If you want to find an element called `units` in any namespace, you could use a wildcard: `xblr.find(".//{*}units")`.

Comment: Re: infrequent - those from standards organizations (e.g., XBRL, ISO) are infrequent, but unfortunately regulatory authority (e.g., SEC) and company-specific schemas are usually reissued at least annually. Re: wildcards - unfortunately does not work in my use case, as I tend to know that I want, for example, `us-gaap:Revenues` or `ifrs:Revenues`, but not necessarily `irs:Revenues` (which is a different concept).

Answer (score 1):

As for the answer to your specific question, why the `attrib` list doesn't contain the namespace prefix decls, sorry for the unquenching answer: because they're not attributes.

`http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace` is a special schema that doesn't act like the other schemas in your userspace. In *that* representation, `xmlns:prefix="uri"` is an attribute. In *all other* subordinate (by parsing sequence) schemas, `xmlns:prefix="uri"` is a special thing, a namespace prefix declaration, which is different than an attribute on a node or element. I don't have a reference for this but it holds true perfectly in at least a half dozen (correct) implementations of XML parsers that I've used, including those from IBM, Microsoft and Oracle.

As for the ugliness of reparsing the file, I feel your pain but it's necessary. As [tdelaney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642070/tdelaney) so well pointed out, you may not assume that all of your namespace decls or prefixes *must* be on your root element.

Be prepared for the *possibility of* the same prefix being redefined with a different namespace on *every node* in your document. This may hold true and the library must correctly work with it, even if it is never the case your document (or worse, if it's *never been the case so far*).

Consider if perhaps you are shoehorning some text processing to parse or query XML when there may be a better solution, like XPath or XQuery. There are some good recent changes to and Python wrappers for Saxon, even though their pricing model has changed.

Comment: Yes, `xmlns:prefix="uri"` is "a special thing", and not a regular attribute. But I don't understand what  the `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace` namespace has to do with that.

Comment: That URI is actually the namespace on the `xml:` prefix. It's the minimal bootstrap for getting a parser set up. Visit it (as a URL) to read more.